# Get Javascript Variable to assign php vaiable

Tags: javascript, php, alert

I am Trying to JavaScript Variable to assign PHP Variable and  my Value to Alert but Getting on error 
the output as
"; alert(simple);

```
var p1sds = "My Custom String";
<?php
$dsfd = "<script>document.writeln(p1sds)</script>";
?>
    var simple = "<?php echo $dsfd ;?>";
      alert(simple);

</script>
```

Comment: What error are you getting, and why do you want to alert a script?

Comment: javascript has to exist inside a `<script>....</script>` tag set. Most of yours does not

Comment: you would have nested script tags by writing the var `$dsfd` within the existing script tags

Comment: yes my code as script inside like that <script></script>

Comment: Then as @RamRaider says, you have a script tags set INSIDE another script tag set

Comment: @RiggsFolly is that just read JavaScript variable

Comment: @RiggsFolly I am using only PHp script inside <script></script>

Answer (score 0):

i needed to do something like this a while ago
i used cookies

```
setCookie("p1sds","My Custom String")
<?php
$dsfd = $_COOKIE["p1sds"]
?>
    var simple = "<?php echo $dsfd ;?>";
      alert(simple);
```

Comment: yes but my custom string output  only JavaScript Value for assign variable as   var p1sds = "My Custom String"; its that ..

Answer (score 0):

It is impossible for you to set PHP variable based off of JavaScript variables, because as far as the JavaScript is concerned, there is no PHP. It's just HTML being echoed or included.
You can do it the other way around (how you have it in cookies) because the PHP will run first and be able to set the variables before the JavaScript runs.

In your example, when you set `$dsfd` to `$dsfd = "<script>document.write...<script>"`, unless you do something more with $dsfd later, there is no effect.

If you are ok with the idea of using more than one page, then you can probably do something with cookies, but then you have to go from page to page to accomplish what you want, and that might be not an options because of something else.

My last thought on this is that you might be able to use something like hidden `<iframe>` elements using PHP to echo variables when the `<iframe>` loads or reloads, but I've never done something like that so I can't say.

Hope something in here is helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Hi I am just changed the following Thinks its Working

```
var p1sds = "My Custom String";
 document.cookie='p1sds='+p1sds; 

<?php
if (isset($_COOKIE["p1sds"])) {
 $asdas= $_COOKIE["p1sds"]; 
}
?>
   var simple = "<?php echo $asdas ;?>";
      alert(simple);

</script>
```